# How to extract string which contains matched string

Tags: python

My code is below which extract all the elements

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

Output

```
https://www.example.com/author/1/
https://www.example.com/about/2/
https://www.example.com/author/3/
```

type of (link['href'])

```
<cls str>
<cls str>
<cls str>
```

I need to extract the url which contains 'about'

I tried with `print(link['href'] if 'about' in link)` which thrown eror

My expected out

```
https://www.example.com/about/2/
```

Comment: What's the error thrown? `print(link['href'] if 'about' in link)` there is already an error in this line. If you are printing `link['href']` why you checking just `link`

Comment: Try: if 'about' in link['herf']: print(link['herf'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional expression requires an `else` clause to specify what the expression should return when the condition is false.

But you don't want to print anything in that case. So use an `if` statement around the `print()` call.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'about' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
```

You could also do the matching in the `soup.find_all()` call.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'about')):
    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: super awesome not aware about `href=re.compile(r'about')):` thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for 'about' in link whereas it seems the word about is found in link['href']. So try to update the if condition as below.

```
print(link['href'] if 'about' in link['href'] else '')
```